# aux line in as midi controller

Tags: midi, keyboard, beginner, midi-controller-keyboard, electronic-music

I'm trying to use my keyboard as a midi controller without a midi wire. I am currently using an aux cable as my connector which only allows me to live record the instrument without being able to control the instrument on my music software(studio one prime), I can only select the notes with my mouse.

is it possible to use an aux connected keyboard as a midi controller and if so what software would be necessary for this function??

Comment: To transmit MIDI data, you need a MIDI cable or a USB cable.

Comment: there's no software out there that can recognise the note I play and use that info as a midi control?

Comment: There is software, but it costs more than a MIDI interface and doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 5):

There IS software that claims to generate MIDI from audio input.  'Imperfect' would be too kind :-)   Use a keyboard that DOES have a MIDI output.  Life's too short to do it the hard way.

Comment: Laurence was too kind, saying that it's imperfect.  All software that I have ever seen doing that, does a terrible job.  Can you show the exact keyboard you are using?

Answer (score 0):

MIDI does a lot more than just recognise what note is being played. The most reliable way to transmit *all* the data is via MIDI plugs and ables. The signal from aux contains different information, which can probably be translated by software, but at the moment, there's going to be garbled messages which are affected by latency. A MIDI 'board is still the best way to go - and most modern 'boards are MIDI equipped.